# How to do handwriting animation in LibreOffice Impress presentations?

Tags: libreoffice, animation

I've got some slides with handwriting-style fonts on them.  Is there a way to do a "handwriting" animation on them?  To make it seem like the text is being written, letter by letter?

I've figured out some effects that sort of fade in from the left, but it's not really a convincing "handwriting" effect.

Comment: Latin fonts do not carry information about the order of lines (I believe that some asian fonts do).  If I needed such an animation I'd try to improvise using inkscape: convert the text to paths and divide the lines myself.  Then use SVG animation (not currently supported by inkscape, but supported by the SVG format) to display the lines one-by-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the "colored lettering" animation (in Entrance -> Moderate), which at least does one letter at a time, slightly better than a horizontal wipe.

As @grochmal says, svg animation would be the only way to get "brushstrokes", but this is a decent half-way point for now.

Bonus points for anyone that can figure out how to get something that looks vaguely like a "blackboard erase" effect for making the text disappear!